# Which CMS offer robust Postgresql support and allow easy CRUD forms design and reports for users with no programmer skills

Tags: postgresql, content-management-system

I'm looking for a free CMS with an active community for building an intranet over a PostgreSQL database. The main objective is to allow the users to build customs forms and reports to fill and consult database without having any programmer skills.

I don't really have preference on the programming language and the CMS need to allow deployment on a Windows Server.

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Comment: SO is not a recommendation engine. Not constructive.

Comment: Ok sorry, if I change the question and ask for the most used CMS with my constraints can you consider it constructive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone is looking for an easy way to build Web forms and reports over a PostgreSQL backend like I was, the PostgreSQL PHP Generator from SQLMaestro is a great product...

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/phpgenerator/